# several versions of numpy installed but all needed in python

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to use `pandas` in Pycharm under `Python27`. Every time I try to import it I get the following error:

```
import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
    'this pandas version'.format(_np_version))
ImportError: this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.9.0
your numpy version is 1.8.1.
Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.9.0 to use this pandas version
```

I noticed that this has to do with the numpy version. Indeed when I do the following it does confirm that the version of `numpy` I have installed is version `1.8.1`.

```
import numpy
numpy.version.version
Out[6]: '1.8.1'
```

This was confusing because in my interpreter settings it shows numpy 1.14.1. I then checked to see what folder it was interpreting `numpy` from:

```
In[8]: numpy.__file__
Out[8]: 'C:\\Program Files\\ParaView 5.2.0-Qt4-OpenGL2-Windows-64bit\\bin\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.pyc'
```

I believe this is the problem, `numpy` is being imported from a different package (`paraview.simple` in this case), which makes use of an earlier version of numpy and includes it within its directory for its own purposes.

I'd like `pandas` to go ahead and use its own `numpy`, but also have `paraview.simple` use its own `numpy`. How can I ensure the packages don't interfere with each other?

Thanks

Comment: Use a virtualenv, or something like conda to easily handle multiple versions of libraries.

Comment: Im looking at this link: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html. I get how to create a virtual environment and add packages to it, but the official docs only show how to add one package at a time. It doesn't address the problem that I have here, where two packages need the same third package, only different versions of it...

Comment: What is `sys.path`?